# Assignment Functions and Quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic

I have been going through "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" By Herbert Enderton covering first order logic and he describes assignment functions which we use to map from the variable set of a language to the universe. He then shows how this is used to ascertain truth on well formed formulas by expanding the assignment function to terms, atomic formulas and well formed formulas.

My main confusion is what happens when multiple quantifiers are next to each other.

Enderton says that given $\vDash_{U} \forall x \phi{[s]} \iff \forall d \in |U| \vDash_{U} \phi{[s(x|d)]}$. This makes sense to me, and I can work out the logic behind it. However, what happens when there are multiple quantifiers?

For example something like this $\vDash_{U} \exists y\forall x \phi{[s]}$?

This is what I figured would be the most logical
$\vDash_{U} \exists y\forall x \phi{[s]} \iff \exists b \in |U|, \forall d \in |U|, \vDash_{U} \phi{[s(x,y|d,b)]}$, where

$s(x, y|d, b)(z)=
 \begin{cases} 
      d & z=x \\
      b & z=y\\
      s(z) & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$

Comment: It should be "$\exists b\in\vert U\vert\forall d\in\vert U\vert$[stuff]:" one of the existentials needs to be a universal, and the order matters (since the quantifiers aren't of the same type).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly for your multiple nested quantifier case it's useful to define your new assignment function $s(x,y|d,b)$ as you expressed from the original assignment function $s$ in order to further define satisfaction of wffs with multiple quantifiers, and obviously such a $s(x,y|d,b)$ exists and is unique as a piecewise function.

And there might be a typo in your expression above, you'd better formalize as:
$$\vDash_{U} \exists y \forall x \phi{[s]} \iff \exists b \in |U|, \forall d \in |U|, \vDash_{U} \phi{[s(x,y|d,b)]}$$

Please note the correct substitution position of $x,y$ with $d,b$ as defined in your own above $s(x,y|d,b)(z)$.